# Error not getting any response from calling an api from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have below code:

apitest.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>WEBPAGE</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function test(){
                const userAction = async () => {
                const response = await fetch('<some_api_url>');
                const myJson = await response.json(); 
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJson
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <button onclick="test()">Click</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>

    </body>

</html>
```

I am trying to demo call GET api whose response is very basic json data:

`{"Status":"OK"}`

but I am not getting the above response. Can anyone please help me resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test` function simply defines a function, `userAction` to make the API request. But this function is never called, so the request is never sent.

Simply add this line:

```
userAction()
```

at the end of the `test` function.

Comment: I have added this line at the end of the test function but nothing seems to be happening. Can you post the code.

Comment: Which code? I  have nothing else to suggest - calling the function should definitely make *something* happen. Are there any errors reported on the console?

Comment: I have been able to do it but the response I am getting is `[object object]` instead of `{'status': 'ok'}`

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I expected from your code. You just need to set the `innerHTML` to `response` if that's the output you want to see.